# Subtypes not being recognized in Subclasses

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have the following code setup;

```
abstract class GenericQuestionEditor() {
    protected abstract var data: GenericQuestionData
}
```

but then when I create `EditorSimple()` it throws an error when I try to set `data` to `DataSimple()`, why?

```
class EditorSimple(): GenericQuestionEditor() {
    override var data = DataSimple()
}
```

my `GenericQeustionData` and `DataSimple()` are setup like this;

```
abstract class GenericQuestionData {}
```

```
class DataSimple: GenericQuestionData() {}
```

it doesn't complain if I create this function in `GenericQuestionEditor()`

```
fun test() {
    data = DataSimple()
}
```

Why do I get an error on `data` in `EditorSimple()`? It should recognize it as a subtype and it should be allowed as I understand.

I feel like the answer is found in the [kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html) but i'm not sure how to configure it in this case since they are not passed values or part of a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the type explicitly:

```
class EditorSimple(): GenericQuestionEditor() {
    override var data: GenericQuestionData = DataSimple()
}
```

Without the type annotation, the type of `data` would be inferred to be `DataSimple`, which doesn't match the type of its super class' `data`. Even though the types are related, you can't override writable a property with a subtype. Imagine if I did:

```
class SomeOtherData: GenericQuestionData()

val editor: GenericQuestionEditor = EditorSimple()
editor.data = SomeOtherData() // data is of type GenericQuestionData, so I should be able to do this
```

But, `editor` actually has a `EditorSimple`, which can only store `DataSimple` objects in `data`!

Comment: @Tenfour04 True, I should have been more specific.

Comment: but then you loose the methods/properties of `DataSimple()` and have to cast it anytime you want to use them. I could hold the cast in memory but that seems less than ideal.

Comment: @glend I've explained why you can't override like this. Are you not convinced by the explanation? You cannot do this unless you make it a `val`.

Comment: If you really need a `DataSimple`, you could make that type a type parameter: `class GenericQuestionEditor<D : GenericQuestionData>() { protected abstract var data: D }` and `class EditorSimple : GenericQuestionEditor<DataSimple>() { … }`.